# Jquery animate width from left to right

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate menu elements shrinking the width from 170 to 150px on mouseover. 
My problem is, with the default .animate shrinking happens on the right side of my rectangle, I need it to shrink on the left side. I have already tried animating left margin, but since I have text inside the element, it shifts on the right during the animation.

This is the actual code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

//When mouse rolls over  
$("#navigation li").mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).stop().animate({marginLeft:'20'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) 

});  

//When mouse is removed  
$("#navigation li").mouseout(function(){  
    $(this).stop().animate({marginLeft:'0'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
});  


});
```

I had found some other answers to this, but I didn't understand the proposed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior. The only way to change this is via CSS

```
#navigation li {
float: right; //Sometimes using float funks things up so...
}
```

or changing the CSS of the parent and the child li (better solution)

```
#navigation_li's_parent {
text-align: right;
}

#navigation li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thaaanks! Was so easy. Text is shifting left when the rectangle shrinks, trying to mantain the right padding I set. I solved it setting the padding in "#navigation li a" instead of "#navigation li".

Comment: New trouble, trying to ask for a followup (tell me if you think it is better do open a new question): how can I disable the animate for the selected link (ie. link home not animated if you are in the home page)? Usually i achieve it using body class and php if, but this time there is the animation I can't disable. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you just check the page's URL, user-side. That way, you can take the unneeded load off your PHP. Like `URL: http://my-site.com/pages/home` then you can parse the page's url in PHP with `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: Thanks NeXXeuS. Since I'm mostly a "copy and paste programmer" I managed to do it in a similar way (I'm on wordpress). I check with wp php (is_page, is_home etc...) which page is active and, if not i put a "sel" class on each button excluding the active one. In the JS animate code I selected only "#navigation sel" elements. Rough... but works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily control this with css positioning. Either with floats or with an inner container that is positioned either left, or right (relative, or absolute).