# jQuery animate the left side of an element

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-animate, block

I have a color block and every time I press on it I want it to shrink.

```
$('#blue').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '90%'},1000);
});
```

But it goes by the right side. How do I make it to shrink on the left side?

CSS:

```
#blue{
height:250px;
width:500px;
background-color:blue;
```

}

html:

```
<div id='blue'></div>
```

Comment: show me your html and css. (but i think your block uses style "float: right;" and you should change it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627260/jquery-animate-width-from-left-to-right `:)` might help. rest first post below is nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could `float: right` the `#blue` element inside a parent (on which you may want to apply some kind of float clearing, if necessary).

or just assign `position: absolute` and `right : 0;` to `#blue` element, inside a parent with `position: relative;`

Comment: Thank you, works fluently. Going to accept the answer in 6mins.

Comment: I'm glad to help. - I would also produce a fiddle, but today it seems not working

Answer (score 1):

use

```
#blue {
float: right;
}
```

OR changing the CSS of the parent and the #blue

```
#blue's_parent {
text-align: right;

}

#blue {
display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
<div id='blue'>
</div>

#blue{
  height:250px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:blue;

}

$('#blue').click(function() {
$(this).animate({
    "width": "-=50px"

}, 1000);
```

});

Try this on Bin http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpca